# Is the following $\varphi$ linear transformation orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

$ \varphi:(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})\rightarrow (\frac{5}{13}x_{3}+\frac{12}{13}x_{4},\frac{12}{13}x_{3}-\frac{5}{13}x_{4},\frac{5}{13}x_{1}-\frac{12}{13}x_{2},-\frac{12}{13}x_{1}+\frac{5}{13}x_{2})$ orthogonal?

I know that I just have to check the matrix of this linear transformation, if that is orthogonal or not, but how can I find the matrix of this linear transformation?

Comment: The images of the basis vectors are the columns of the matrix $A$. Then check whether or not $AA^T=I$.

Comment: In row $i$ and column $j$ write down the coefficient of $x_j$ in the $i$-th term on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that I just have to check the matrix of this linear transformation, if that is orthogonal or not, but how can I find the matrix of this linear transformation?

Consider
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1}x_1+a_{1,2}x_2+\ldots+a_{1,n}x_n\\
a_{2,1}x_1+a_{2,2}x_2+\ldots+a_{2,n}x_n\\
\vdots\\
a_{n,1}x_1+a_{n,2}x_2+\ldots+a_{n,n}x_n
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \dots & a_{1,n}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \dots & a_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \dots & a_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}
$$
Example:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x_1+x_3\\2x_2-x_3\\x_1+5x_2\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} x_1+\color{red}{0\cdot x_2}+x_3\\\color{red}{0\cdot x_1}+2x_2-x_3\\x_1+5x_2+\color{red}{0\cdot x_3}\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&2&-1\\1 & 5 & 0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}
$$